# WordPress custom field permalink

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

We're creating a WordPress website that uses custom posts and custom fields. We're using the "Custom Post Type Permalinks" plugin for our links and "Custom Post Type UI" for our posts.

Our current links are like:

```
http://example.com/<custom post type>/<custom taxonomy>/<custom post slug>
```

Example:

```
http://example.com/my-custom-post/my-custom-taxonomy/my-post-slug
```

What we're trying to achieve is:

```
http://example.com/<custom taxonomy>/<custom post slug>
```

Example:

```
http://example.com/my-custom-taxonomy/my-post-slug
```

Although it is achievable by setting the custom post values to the following:

- Rewrite: True
- Custom Rewrite Slug: %my-custom-taxonomy%
- With Front: False

But when I do that the link goes to a 404 page. It seems that WordPress cannot find the post or recognize the custom post.

We already did the `flush_rewrite_rules()` but the problem stays the same.

How can I make the link open the requested post?

Comment: The pro version of permalink manager, would be an easy solution

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/